# Running Python batch files from windows search window - why I can`t start a program that uses selenium and Firefox this way?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a bunch of bat files to start my Python scripts from command line (that is using cmd). But it turnes out that I don`t even have to move into command line because if I type the name of the batch file in windows 10 search window the code start running. With one exception, though.

I have got a script that uses selenium and Firefox. When I start it with batch file from windows 10 search window it quits when it gets to the code line with Firefox. If I start it from command line it works, as it should.

Here is a simple example of the type of code I am writing about:

```
#! python3

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

And here is the code from the batch file:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\PC\Desktop\python_work\name_of_the_file.py %*
```

Intrestingly, when I exchange in the Python script Firefox for Chrome the problem dissappears. Here is the version of code that starts and keeps running if I start it with the same batch file from the windows 10 search window:

```
#! python3

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I`d appreciate any help with the following questions:

What is the difference between starting a batchfile from windows 10 search window and from command line?

Why can`t I start a program that uses selenium and Firefox this way? Is there a way to fix it?